# perspective camera with libgdx

Tags: camera, libgdx, perspective

I am trying to setup a viewport using perspective camera. I am trying to render a scene like this [image: scrolls screenshot]
   I read an official blog post about the cameras and found a few tests within gdx test suits. However, I am still kinda confused. I have no idea how to manipulate the test suits nor i have any idea what the code does other than just following the code given in the test.

I have a couple of sub-questions,

- was the game in the screenshot rendered with perspective camera or just the grids?
- Is it possible to work with Orthographic and Perspective Camera at the same time? so that i can render different elements with different camera?
- Is there any detailed and easy to understand guide that explain perspective camera really well? I find libgdx severely lack of documentation regrading these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> was the game in the screenshot rendered with perspective camera or just the grids?

I think it's 2D. Just because of there're no true 3D objects.

> Is it possible to work with Orthographic and Perspective Camera at the same time?

Yes, it is possible. [Example and explanation.](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1615&p=9122&hilit=Camera#p9122)

> Is there any detailed and easy to understand guide that explain perspective camera really well?

Very good tutorial about cameras in libgdx: [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectionViewportCamera)

[More links about mixing 2D and 3D](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/mixedUI)

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to a blog by Mario Zechner on the Camera classes:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200427232345/https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1550

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thanks for contributing. Links are great, but a good answer should be self contained - they should help solve the problem even if the links go dead. Please consider editing your answer to summarize the information you linked to.